# Why does tmux require setting 256 color mode manually?

Tags: terminal, colors, tmux

I just logged-in to a machine and realized that the colors changed inside tmux. It seems like even with `TERM=xterm-256color` and `tput colors` ⇒ 256 tmux switches to `TERM=screen` and `tput colors` ⇒ 8.

Explicitly setting

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

in `.tmux.conf` helps but I would like to know why it is changed in the first place.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `tmux` doesn't change to `TERM=xterm` on its own; not just because it removes 256 color support, but also because `xterm` and variants don't work properly inside `tmux`. It must be one of your shell startup files setting this variable.

Comment: @egmont I don't think so. I am currently on windows/MSYS2/mingw and it has xterm-256color/256 by default. Using ssh to log into 2 machines (Debian/Ubuntu) I have xterm-256color/256 on both. Launching tmux I get screen/8 on both. Something else I could check?

Comment: I see you fixed your post to say `TERM=screen` instead of `TERM=xterm`. I don't know why 256 color gets lost, sorry.